# unable to Receive and parse Multipart as well as Text data in Node JS on Azure Function

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-functions, multipartform-data

I am creating a Azure Function in Node JS. I need to send Multipart data(images or files) as well as Text data(other information like where to save the file and etc).

From UI I am sending data(both files and Text) as a Form Data (new FormData())

On Azure Function I am using **parse-multipart** to Read the Multipart data.

My Azure Function Looks like this.

```
var stream = require('stream');
var multipart = require("parse-multipart");
module.exports = async function (context, req) {

  var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);
  // get boundary for multipart data e.g. ------WebKitFormBoundaryDtbT5UpPj83kllfw
  var boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
  // parse the body
  var parts = multipart.Parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);
    var fileStream0 = new stream.Readable();
    fileStream0.push(parts[0].data);
    fileStream0.push(null);
    // Further Uses this Stream to save files to Azure Storage
}
```

This Code works fine Since I am able to save the File. But Unfortunately not able to retrieve Text Values sent in Form Data.

Answer (score 0):

That `parts` variable is any array with each item being one field of the form submitted. So you would have to loop over that array to fetch all the fields sent.

I believe you would have to change your code to something like this

```js
var stream = require('stream');
var multipart = require("parse-multipart-data");

module.exports = async function (context, req) {

  var bodyBuffer = Buffer.from(req.body);
  // get boundary for multipart data e.g. ------WebKitFormBoundaryDtbT5UpPj83kllfw
  var boundary = multipart.getBoundary(req.headers['content-type']);
  // parse the body
  var parts = multipart.parse(bodyBuffer, boundary);
  for (var part of parts) {
    if(part.filename) {
      // handle file
    } else {
      // handle other form field
    }
  }
}
```